# A discrepancy in understanding another formula.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

If I have:

$$\phi_{n}(z) = \chi_{n}(A(z)),(z \in \mathbb{C}, |z| = 1) $$ and $$\chi_n(A(z))=z^n+z^{n-1}z^{-1}+\cdots zz^{-n+1}+z^{-n},$$

Why $z^m - z^{-m} = \phi_{m} - \phi_{m-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Just look at a few examples: 
$$\phi_1 = z + z^{-1}$$
$$\phi_2 = z^2 + 1 + z^{-2}$$
$$\phi_3 = z^3 + z + z^{-1} + z^{-3}$$
$$\phi_4 = z^4 + z^2 + 1 + z^{-2} + z^{-4}.$$
What instead seems to be true is that $$\phi_n - \phi_{n-2} = z^n + z^{-n}$$ which you can prove using $$\phi_n(z) = \frac{z^{n+1} - 1/z^{n+1}}{z - 1/z}.$$

Comment: So you mean that my formula contains something wrong?